# How to add new key inside json blob in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a SQL table `MYTABLE` similar to the below example

```
id.     config
123.    {"location":zxc, 'zip_code':1234} 
143.    {"location":zxc, 'zip_code':1222}
```

I need to do a database migration where I add a key  `name` inside the config JSON so the config becomes. {"name": "abc", "location":zxc, 'zip_code':1234}

I am not sure how to do this. I can do ALTER TABLE, ADD COLUMN but this is different than adding/removing a column.

Please suggest.

EDIT:

This is in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes it is Postgres. See edits, please. Can you please write the full query?

Comment: @nad You didn't provide enough details in the question to write a query. At least show us the query you already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an UPDATE statement:

```
update mytable
  set config = config || '{"name": "abc"}' ;
```

The above assumes that `config` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's a `json` column, you need to cast it: `set config = config::jsonb || '{"name": "abc"}'`

Answer (score 2):

The `jsonb_set()` function can be used to add properties to the current JSON object in PostgreSql ([details](https://haselt.com/blog/working-with-postgresql-jsonb)). So, for example, you can use the following to set the `name` property to a value of `abc`:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET config = jsonb_set(config, '{name}','"abc"', TRUE)
Where id=1
```

Comment: I changed 'data' with 'config'.  Great spot.  Thanks, @Jeremy Caney

Answer (score -2):

Since you say it's a migration, I am guessing you are copying rows from an old table to a new table. So, you can modify the value as you are inserting each row. (If you are keeping the same table, change the INSERT statement into an UPDATE statement.) If your JSON is really simple like in your example, then some simple string manipulation should be good enough.

```
insert NewTable (id, config)
select id,
    '{"name": "' + name + '", ' + SUBSTRING(config, 2, DATALENGTH(config) - 1)
    from OldTable;
```

I'm guessing name is another column in this table. If not, modify it to find the name from the right place.